# Interpreting interactions with dummy variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data, interaction

I have the following equation

[image]

and am trying to interpret the interactions. So for example, for interpreting the interaction *maledemo*, would I add the coefficients for the constant, *male, demo* and *maledemo*? or do I need to include coefficients for the other interactions involving *male* and *demo* as well?

Also, how would I interpret the interaction for *maleage*?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? In what sense do you want to interpret it? What is it you want to understand about the interaction?

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer your question if you provided a more information about your predictors. I assume that _age_ is a continuous predictor? (so they are not all dummy variables?) in that case the interaction between _age_ and _male_ would indicate the change in the slope with respect to _age_ in males with respect to your baseline (I guess females). For the interactions between dummy variables, they represents a change in intercept, but the interpretations depends also on how the contrasts are coded

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming age is a continuous variable. The 0.0066 maleage coefficient should be added to the coefficient of age (-0.0059 + 0.0066) and interpreted as the coefficient of the slope between fempres and age when the person is male. The coefficient of the slope for age of -0.0059 is the relationship between fempres and age when the person is female.

If demo is a dummy variable then maledemo only makes a difference for persons where demo=1 and male=1. The maledemo coefficient should be added to demo and male coefficients (and the coefficient of any other dummy variables that =1 for that person) to give the intercept when demo=1 and male=1. If male=0 or demo=0 maledemo will be 0*-0.2159 so doesn't change the intercept. If demo is continuous use the same approach as above for age.